# Show hint text On Text("I'm text" , hint : " my hint " ) flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to show hint text on Text() in flutter like android. But I did not find any hint key related to TextView in flutter.

Like this.

```
 Text("", hint : "Choose State")
```

Comment: You are using it for input?

Comment: Use Textfield instead of Text for hintText

Comment: I just use Text to click and select value to set on same Text. But before nothing selected I just want to so hint on that Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it self.

```
var selectedValue = null;
Text(selectedValue ?? "Choose Country")
```

If `selectedValue` is `null` then I will show optional value ie. `"Choose Country"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `textfield` that will have the property `decoration` of type `InputDecoration` and that will contain a `hintText` property:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: 'Choose State'
  ),
);
```

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-input

Comment: I just use Text to click and select value to set on same Text. But before nothing selected I just want to so hint on that Text